Old drivers for S2 3650 CI dont work on Windows 11
I have an USB satellite receiver, S2 3650 CI with old drivers. My Q is if I can update the drivers based on the old ones. I have an Original CD with software + drivers, and firmware for the device. My Win 11 can't detect the device because the old drivers are unusable.
Can anyone help? Thanks.

The difference between Win10 and 11 is very low regarding the non-UI components. USB devices are visible in Windows device manager even without driver. There you can make Windows to load an driver from an inf file + dll and whatever belongs to the driver. Even if the driver can not be used on Windows 11 will try it and in the end show an error dialog. Therefore there is no update needed or if it doesn't work the driver has to be modified on code level, which is even complicated if you have the source code, by reverse engineering it is getting even more complicated.
